# Content split with page create in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve content split with page create by JavaScript.

The logic is, if left col or right's height is greater than 650px then container 2 will be appended and the section will cut from 1st page and continue on second page from that point with the section headline.

1st page will be 2 column and rest of the pages content will be full width.

Also attached a illustration to demonstrate how it should look.
[image]

It will be appreciated if anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2pmw0pm/

Comment: I am still not completely clear oi

Comment: Arathi - can you pls let me know where re you not clear? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I think I figured it out, to mean exactly when content exceeds height 650. Off the top of my head I dont know how (if) that could get done, that is how to detect the point at which to break the content off based on height.

Comment: Yes correct. That's what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Using [.innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) was a good idea, you should have carried on this way.

I made a [fiddle where it only works for the right column](https://jsfiddle.net/dsbcvtjr/), but I'm sur you'll know how to handle both using it.

---

Here is the JS part of the code :

```
var leftColHeight = $('.col-left').innerHeight();
var rightColHeight = $('.col-right').innerHeight();

var divs = [];

var heights = 0;
var toShow;

if (leftColHeight > 650 || rightColHeight > 650) {
    $('.col-right').innerHeight(650).css("overflow", "hidden");
    $('.col-right > div').each(function() {
        divs.push($(this));
        if(toShow === undefined)
        {
            heights += $(this).height();
            if (heights >= 650)
            {
                toShow = divs.length-1;
            }
        }
    });
    $('body').append('<div class="container2"></div>');

    for (var div in divs)
    {
        if(div >= toShow)
        {
            $('.container2').append(divs[div].html());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit :**
Here is [my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/recewjb4/) with something that's close to what you're looking for.

But you should know that, considering that your containers have not the same width and with plain JS or CSS, you can't get what has been overflowed. (*But if you find a way, I'd love to know it)*.
Take a look at libraries such as [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) (for [ellipsies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Values), but it maywork with simple overflow).

Comment: Thanks for your effort Tektiv, I am stuck at the point where It needs to be split in between the section and instead of append complete section in container 2, it should continue with the rest of the content of that section

Comment: @Bryce77 Updated my answer + Added a [new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/recewjb4/), does it fit what you need or at least help you ?

Comment: Yes almost there what I am looking for. Only one thing, few words are repeating for Section 5 on page 2. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Bryce77 Yeah I know, that is because both containers have different widths. If they had the same, you could use `excess` value in the `top` css property of the `.container2 > div > div`. But here, we can't :/

Comment: Yup...Thanks a ton mate.